# Extract 2nd element after <br/>

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to extract `United States` from the following:

```
address = '1 McDonalds Dr<br/>OAK BROOK, IL 60523-1911<br/>United States'
```

I tried:

```
for br in address.find_all('br', limit=2):
    result = br.next_sibling
    print(result)
```

And it returned:

```
OAK BROOK, IL 60523-1911
United States
```

How do you extract only `United States` from it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there!

```
for br in address.find_all('br', limit=2):
    result = br.next_sibling
    print(result)
```

This loops over all `<br>` tags and then executes the loop body for each. Since your `address` contains two `<br>` tags, you will get two results. Since you only want to get the result from the *second* result, you will simply have to not loop over it but access the second element directly:

```
second_br = address.find_all('br', limit=2)[1]
result = second_br.next_sibling
print(result) # United States
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`.contents`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children) property of bs4. If you check the `contents` of `address` you'll see that the text you want is in the last index. You can access it by using `contents[-1]`.

```
>>> address.contents
["1 McDonalds Dr", <br/>, 'OAK BROOK, IL 60523-1911', <br/>, "United States"]
>>> result = address.contents[-1]
>>> result
"United States"
```